# how to make layouts transparent on click

Tags: android, android-layout

I have two layouts and one imageView. The parent layout linearLayout1 have image background and its child layout relativeLayout1 have dark background. So when i move imageView on screen it display a selective area of linearLayout1 image . I applied touch motion but no idea how to display selective area. the code is here

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

// RelativeLayout viewRelative;
ImageButton imgBtnTarget;
Animation aniRotate, aniZoom;
PointF downPoint = new PointF();// Record Mouse Position When Pressed Down
PointF strtPointImg = new PointF(); // Record Start Position of 'img'

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    imgBtnTarget = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButtontTarget);

    imgBtnTarget.setOnTouchListener( new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            // for moving image
            switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                PointF mv = new PointF(event.getX() - downPoint.x, event
                        .getY() - downPoint.y);
                imgBtnTarget.setX((int) (strtPointImg.x + mv.x));
                imgBtnTarget.setY((int) (strtPointImg.y + mv.y));
                strtPointImg = new PointF(imgBtnTarget.getX(), imgBtnTarget.getY());
                break;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

}

and here is xml resource

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/back" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeViewBlack"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/black" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButtontTarget"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/target" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

In Java code:

```
LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.your_ll_id);
ll.setAlpha(TRANSPARENT_VALUE);
```

Or:

```
ll.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

If you want transparent all from the begining add to your Layout in XML:

```
android:background="#00ffffff"
```

EDIT:

```
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                v.setAlpha(0.5f);
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                v.setAlpha(1.0f);
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                //your code...
                break;
            }
            return true;
        }
```

Comment: your answer is welcome but my requirement is just i want to transparent where my imageView moved. can you suggest any thing else